# define a function using an iterative function

Tags: python, function, iteration

I have some function FUN(a, b): on two characters. I want to define another function foo(s), such that

```
foo(s):
    FUN(a[0],a[1])
    FUN(a[2],a[3])
    FUN(a[4],a[5])
    ...
```

for all characters in s (assume s is even length). My thoughts are that we basically need to run FUN(a,b) (len(s)%2) times, but I'm not sure how to iterate a function in that way, while also making sure FUN has the right inputs. Any ideas?

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(s), 2): FUN(s[i], s[i+1])` or `for i in range(0, len(s), 2): FUN(*s[i:i+2])`

Comment: @falsetru I like my answer better :P

Comment: @GamesBrainiac well, your answer is less readable and probably worse performance-wise than falsetru's comment. I definitely wouldn't prefer it...

Answer (score 2):

Well this would be easy to do with `zip`:

```
def fun(a, b):
    print a, b


def foo(s):
    for x, y in zip(s[::2], s[1::2]):
        fun(x, y)


foo("12345678")
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

A more efficient way, using generators, would be using `izip` (same output):

```
from itertools import izip


def fun(a, b):
    print a, b


def foo(s):
    for x, y in izip(s[::2], s[1::2]):
        fun(x, y)


foo("12345678")
```

Comment: thanks this is similiar to what i wanted. what would the easiest way be to concatenate all the outputs into a single string?

Answer (score 1):

When a question ist tagged with `iteration` there must be a way to do it with `iter`. :-)

```
values = range(10)

def do_work(x, y):
    print('{}_{}'.format(x, y))

it = iter(values)
try:
    while it:
        do_work(next(it), next(it))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Nice suggestion from l4mpi:

```
it = iter(values)
for value in it:
    do_work(value, next(it))
```

Comment: Erm, using exceptions for program flow is a bad idea. They're supposed to catch errors. Atleast, thats what I'm used to anyways.

Comment: This can be rewritten as a for loop: `for x in it: do_work(x, next(it))` - avoids catching the StopIteration, but only works for input with an even number of elements. @GamesBrainiac you don't have any idea how a `for` loop is implemented in python, do you? It uses the same `StopIteration` exception to find out when the sequence it iterates over runs out of values - and that's required, as iterators in python _by design_ only have a `next` method, but no `has_more` or `is_empty` method.

Comment: I knew that there had to be a simple solution. :-( A lot of years with Python and still learning. :-)